# How to remove arrow from PrimeReact OverlayPanel?

Tags: css, primereact

[image: Overlay with arrow]

This question relates to the [OverlayPanel](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact-v6/#/overlaypanel) component in PrimeReact.

I'm looking to remove the small arrow between the overlay panel and its appending element (as can be seen in the image above).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting the `content` style to `none` as follows:

```
p-overlaypanel {
    &:before {
        content:none;
    }

    &:after {
        content:none;
    }

    margin-top: 0px; # removes the gap between menu and anchor element after arrow-removal
}
```